# Make Path- Dependent Gradient on Trendline in Excel 2011

Tags: excel, graph, graphics, spreadsheet

I have generated a fairly complex scatterplot in Excel - the trendline loops back on itself, kind of looks like spaghetti, etc... - and would like to color the line so that, starting from the first datapoint and moving along the line, it changes color from red to violet (i.e. progresses through the spectrum).

Here is the uncolored graph:

[Price v. Volatility Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhAbm.png)

For those of you familiar with protein spatial models, this would be similar to a 2D analog of the following:

[Protein Structure Color Gradient Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F27lE.jpg)

Any pointers would be extremely helpful! Thanks!